# BO Webi - Looking to Display a Blank Instead of a Calculation

Tags: business-objects

I am trying to write a variable to display a blank instead of a calculated value. My report takes two date and time fields and subtracts them. Sometimes, one of the fields can be blank. This causes an issue because the variable will display a calculation instead of a null/blank. Attached a screenshot of sample data. I have included the formulas used below. Any suggestions would be a big help.

[image]

CT Time Diff (Started to Completed)

```
=(((DaysBetween([CT Exam Started Date & Time];[CT Completed Date & Time]))*1440)+(ToNumber(Substr(FormatDate([CT Completed Date & Time];"HH:mm:ss");1 ;2))-ToNumber(Substr(FormatDate([CT Exam Started Date & Time];"HH:mm:ss");1 ;2)))*60+(ToNumber(Substr(FormatDate([CT Completed Date & Time];"HH:mm:ss");4 ;2))-ToNumber(Substr(FormatDate([CT Exam Started Date & Time];"HH:mm:ss");4 ;2))))
```

CT Started to Completed Time (MM)

```
=If (([CT Time Diff (Started to Completed)]) >= 0) Then [CT Time Diff (Started to Completed)]
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Adding an IsNull should do it:

```
=If [CT Time Diff (Started to Completed)]) >= 0
 And Not(IsNull([CT Exam Started Date & Time]))
 Then [CT Time Diff (Started to Completed)]
```

Your TimeDiff function is overly complex.  Try:

```
=TimeBetween([CT Exam Started Date & Time];[CT Completed Date & Time];MinutePeriod)
```

Comment: Thank you so much, that works great! The only thing I had to change was I think there was an extra ")" in the first part of the first formula but I removed it and all is well. I also used your TimeDiff formula.